# How to disable the new tooltips that started a day or two ago?

Tags: support, tooltips

A day or two ago, new tooltips appeared giving directions to new users on how to use the site. For example explaining how to upvote a question, etc...

[image]

They are a good idea for new users, but they are quite annoying for those that have been on SO for a number of years. I have checked my profile settings and I can't find a place to turn them off. How do I disable them?

It would seem that these only need to be displayed to a new user once with a checkbox, something like:

```
[x] Okay got it!
```

(similar to)

[image]

(even though this isn't my first question...)

That way they can be dismissed and not keep popping back up every time I accidentally (or intentionally) mouseover the arrows (or the hands-clapping, etc..)

Comment: Btw, they are called tooltips, not callouts. This seems to be the only question you've asked here. And also, these have suddenly appeared in SE with no warning not too long ago.

Comment: @mindstormsboi They haven't "suddenly appeared" they've always been there but there's generally a delay in them showing up, so if you don't hover for at least a half second, you won't see them. We're looking into adding the delay back but we probably won't make them permanently disappear.

Comment: I joined StackOverlow in the first part of 2014 and I never saw them until a couple of days ago. If that was due to a delay, then adding it back should be fine. Looks like the delay for normal tooltips is 1 sec. That delay for popover__tooltips would also work nicely.

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be any way to block them in the Stack Exchange site preferences, and what's worse, there's no way to block them with an "element picker" since they disappear as soon as you try to activate the element picker, even if you use a shortcut key for it! So, you have to fix this manually.

In uBlock Origin "My Filters", add:

```
stackoverflow.com##div.s-popover__tooltip
stackexchange.com##div.s-popover__tooltip
```

and Apply Changes. They should then be gone. If you use other Stack sites with different domains, like Math Overflow, add those too.